# Строка в u32string. Как выполнить uppercase?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

Использую строку u32string. Как выполнить преобразование uppercase, то есть маленькие символы преобразовать в большие?

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Читайте код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    u32string us;

    us.push_back('a');
    us.push_back('b');
    us.push_back('c');

    cout << (char)us[0] << (char)us[1] << (char)us[2] << endl;

    std::transform(us.begin(), us.end(), us.begin(), ::toupper);

    cout << (char)us[0] << (char)us[1] << (char)us[2] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```